# How to drop the rows from dataframe that have all column values as zero or boolean false

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

How to drop the rows from dataframe that has all column values as zero using pandas? In the dataframe below I use `(df.ix[:,'a':] == 0)` but how do I then vectorize testing all Boolean values for each row are False?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0], 'b':[1,0,0,0], 'c':[1,0,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0,0]}, index=['aa','bb','cc','dd'])
df.index.name = 'name'

      a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
bb    0  0  0  0
cc    1  0  1  0
dd    0  0  0  0
```

I want to drop bb and dd rows from dataframe, as all the column values are empty.Theres is way to drop columns in pandas but nothing for rows.

Comment: Sorry but this question is a little misleading, your df shows that those rows are not empty or boolean false, they have all `0`s so are you asking to drop rows where columns 'a' onwards have all `0`s? If so can you edit your question

Comment: Sorry but the values you mention are 0 not False. Can you fix the question? Currently it's confusing and not a reusable resource for other users looking for answers. Unless you mean "compare `(df.ix[:,'a':] == 0)` then use `all()` on those"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted `mask` comparing all columns from `a` with `0`, where all values in a row are `True` by [`all(axis=1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
mask = ~(df.ix[:,'a':] == 0).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  name  a  b  c  d
0   aa  1  1  1  1
2   cc  1  0  1  0
```

Another solution with checking at least one `1` return same output:

```
print ((df.ix[:,'a':]).any(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (df[(df.ix[:,'a':]).any(1)])
  name  a  b  c  d
0   aa  1  1  1  1
2   cc  1  0  1  0
```

If `name` is index name and first column is index:

```
print (df[~(df == 0).all(1)])
      a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
cc    1  0  1  0
```

Or:

```
print (df[df.any(1)])
      a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
cc    1  0  1  0
```

Comment: (I think 'name' was intended to be the index, makes this slightly simpler.)

Comment: Thank you, I add it to answer.

Comment: Can we use column index instaed of name? that makes logic more dynamic, index from 4 or 3 something of that sorts.

Comment: Do you think set index from column `Name`? Then use `df = df.set_index('Name')` or `df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)`

Comment: @danielhadar - Sorry, if check revision of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38721577/revisions), I was earllier. Only I change solution for first column as index in same time as you. Please check it.

Comment: @danielhadar - So I think you change solution by me ;)

Comment: @danielhadar - no problem, it happens sometimes.

Comment: You should have mentioned it was specifically comparing that **all values in a row are `True`** with `all(axis=1)`, and explicitly mentioned the `axis=1` parameter.

Comment: @smci - sorry, yes, it is better. thank you from edit.

Comment: ...and doing so in a vectorized way (without needing an unnecessary and unvectorized crappy `.apply(lambda row: all(row) == True, axis=1)`

Comment: @smci - I think if use `apply`, it is not vectorized anymore, why do you think `apply`  is vectorize?

Comment: @jezrael: That's exactly what I wrote: "unvectorized apply". I'm saying all apply calls are unvectorized, and that's not what the OP wanted and undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), which returns `True` iff there's any `True` value (i.e. a value different that 0).

```
df = df[df.any(axis=1)]
```

As for your example, before:

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]:       a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
bb    0  0  0  0
cc    1  0  1  0
dd    0  0  0  0
```

And after:

```
      a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
cc    1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Never iterate when you can aggregate along an axis!